# Delete 28 Characters before a matching pattern and replace with a letter

Tags: regex, unix, sed, terminal, cut

I Have a long file in which i want to delete 27 characters before a match and replace a letter before the match

```
example 123456789123456789123456789Replace
```

so the output should be

```
"aReplace"
```

(deleting 28 letters before 'Replace' and add letter 'a' in-front of 'Replace')

i didn't use the actual file and pattern its too big

Comment: its a long file i want to delete 27 letters before the matching pattern the pattern here is "Replace"
after deleting i want a character (in this example its 'a') 'a' to be put in-front of 'Replace' so the output will look like 'aReplace' @AriTrachtenberg

Comment: Sometimes you say "delete 28" and sometimes you say "delete 27". The test string you show has 27 characters before `Replace`. Could you be consistent in your question?

Comment: @user3723229, You really need to be more precise and clear when you ask a question. Not only is there the discrepancy with the number of characters you mention, you show the output in quotes. Is it with or without quotes? It does make a difference in how someone answers a question you know.

Comment: Sorry i was confused its 28 any how thats

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly 28 characters right before `Replace` (per the title of your question) to be replaced by the letter `a`, you do it with

```
sed 's/.\{28\}Replace/aReplace/'
```

Note that the string you gave had just 27 characters though… (as reflected also by the body of your text) - so you would want

```
sed 's/.\{27\}Replace/aReplace/'
```

to get `aReplace` in lines that had `123456789123456789123456789Replace`.

Assuming your text file is `myFile.txt`, your complete command is

```
cat myFile.txt | sed 's/.\{27\}Replace/aReplace/' > newFile.txt
```

This puts the modified contents into the new file `newFile.txt` - it allows you to confirm it worked as planned before you overwrite the input file...

Comment: You forgot the quotes `"` around aReplace.

Comment: @l'L'l - I don't need them? Why would I quote a string?

Comment: The output shows they want `"aReplace"` not `aReplace`

Comment: Pretty sure that OP is not asking to add the quotes since the text states "deleting 28 letters _(sic)_ before 'Replace' and add letter 'a' in front of 'Replace'"

Comment: One never knows, but clearly shows `so the output should be
"aReplace"` with quotes

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner that might be helpful.

```
perl -pe 's/.{27}(?=Replace)/a/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
echo '123456789123456789123456789Replace' | sed -e 's/.\{27\}Replace/"aReplace"/g'
```

output:

```
"aReplace"
```

Comment: Your expression is assuming that the 27 characters start at the beginning of a line `^` - I don't think that is explicitly stated in the question.